# SQL conversion failed when converting nvarchar value to data type int on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, type-conversion, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following query

```sql
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE Id IN (@Input)
```

where the @Input is a multi-value parameter from SSRS and Id is an integer on the database.

When I try to run it with a single value, it works; but when I try to use 2 values, such as '123,124', it always throws the error mentioned in the title.

I tried a bunch of different solution that showed up on Google, but none of them work at all, or it just returns an empty result (when I cast Id to varchar)

How can I make it work with the multi-value parameter?

Comment: What you have above should be all that is required as long as you query is directly in your dataset and NOT a stored procedure. There is no need to do any kind of JOIN/SPLIT etc. Also, leave the SSRS parameter as text (even though it's an integer)

Comment: Is your parameter's DATA TYPE set to **Text** and not **Integer**?

Comment: It is text and it returns that error. I believe it is because the data type for Id is Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when passing the parameter values to the dataset, first you need to convert your input parameter values to the list of CSV values.

For example, if your parameter is like:

[image]

With properties such as:

[image]

You should consume that in your dataset using JOIN function.

e.g.:

```
=JOIN(Parameters!input.Value,",")
```

It should look like:

[image]

Now, your dataset will view/receive `@input` as `'123,456,789'`

And, now you can use any split function to split the values and can use them in your `SQL`.

In case if there is no split function available, you can use any custom SQL (an example given below) to change the multiple values to a single-valued table:

e.g.:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(MAX) = '123,456,789'
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Multi') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Multi;
CREATE TABLE #Multi (value  INT);
DECLARE @Insert VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO #Multi VALUES ('''+REPLACE(@input,',','''),(''')+''');';
EXEC (@Insert);
SELECT value FROM #Multi
```

Will return following output:

[image]

And you final SQL should be SQL chunk given above and:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE Id IN (SELECT value FROM #Multi)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM A
JOIN #Multi M ON A.Id=M.value
```

Hope this help.

Comment: What I was missing in my case was that custom SQL code for splitting the string. I assumed there was an easier way to do this but apparently not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS passes multi value parameters as a string when multiple options are selected. You can verify this by running SELECT @Input. It should see '123,124'. To pass these to your query, I would split them, cast them as an ints, then run them in your query. Something along the lines of:

```
DECLARE @ssrs_input NVARCHAR(MAX) = @input
DECLARE @input_tbl TABLE (
  input INT
  )

WHILE CHARINDEX(',',@ssrs_input) > 0
BEGIN
  INSERT @input_tbl 
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@ssrs_input,0,CHARINDEX(',',@ssrs_input)) AS INT)
  SET @ssrs_input = SUBSTRING(@ssrs_input,CHARINDEX(',',@ssrs_input)+1,LEN(@ssrs_input))
END

INSERT @input_tbl 
    SELECT CAST(@ssrs_input AS INT)

SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN @input_tbl ON
    a.Id = @input_tbl.input
```

Word of warning, the cost of this increases when your number of inputs gets large. If you plan on having a lot of options with a select all, you may want to explore other avenues.

Comment: The potential inputs for this query can be over 14000 so that might be an issue.